# Spring security + spring social without xml

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-facebook

I'm trying to create a login interface only with a Facebook login. And I would like that once logged in the user stay logged and disconnect if he wants.

I don't want the user to register via login/pass, only facebook so once he's logged I only keep information facebook gave me(mail,name etc.).

I followed the tutorial here : http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form

And tried to figure it out with this : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-social-samples/blob/master/spring-social-showcase-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/social/showcase/config/SecurityConfig.java

But I can't make it work, it always say :

> org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource
>   not found

i use maven and not graddle, here is my pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>cinemagik</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-dep</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.sitebricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>0.8.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.13.0-rc0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.M2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <start-class>app.Application</start-class>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
        <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
        <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<name>cinemagik</name>
```

I tried multiple version of spring-ldap from the last release to the 1.3.1.

Here is my code :

WebAppConfiguration

```
package app.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"app"})
public class WebAppConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/images/");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig :

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package app.configuration;

/**
 *
 * @author Antoine
 */
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.Encryptors;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.encrypt.TextEncryptor;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

/**
 * Security Configuration.
 *
 * @author Craig Walls
 */
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @Inject
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.jdbcAuthentication()
                .dataSource(dataSource)
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, true from Account where username = ?")
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, 'ROLE_USER' from Account where username = ?")
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/**/*.css", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.jpg");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/signin")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/signin/authenticate")
                .failureUrl("/signin?param.error=bad_credentials")
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/signout")
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/admin/**", "/favicon.ico", "/resources/**", "/auth/**", "/signin/**", "/signup/**", "/disconnect/facebook").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .rememberMe();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public TextEncryptor textEncryptor() {
        return Encryptors.noOpText();
    }

}
```

Thanks for any help :o

Comment: What do you need spring-security-ldap for? Can't you just remove it?

Comment: @EnableWebSecurity is using it :/

Comment: No it isn't. Look again.

Comment: I don't need spring-security-ldap but everytime I tried to configure my application with an @EnableWebSecurity. I get an error :/

Comment: I don't know what that error is, but it has nothing to do with LDAP. So how about removing that dependency and we can look at something that might be the real problem.